# Обработка нажатия нескольких кнопок

Tags: ооп, java, swing

Одна за одной. Кому не лень прочитать [код](http://ideone.com/ujTn9). Думаю, идея довольно понятна (простой калькулятор).

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class calc_97_lvl {

    public static JLabel jlab;

    calc_97_lvl() {

        ListenCalc LC = new ListenCalc();

        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Калькулятор Кузнецова");
        jfrm.setSize(185, 157);
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
        JLabel jlab = new JLabel();
        jlab.setText("egeherjrj!");
        jlab.setSize(150, 150);

        JButton but1 = new JButton("+");
        JButton but2 = new JButton("-");
        JButton but3 = new JButton("*");
        JButton but4 = new JButton("/");
        JButton but5 = new JButton(".");
        JButton but6 = new JButton("e");
        JButton but7 = new JButton("=");

        JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton b0 = new JButton("0");

        but1.addActionListener(LC);
        but2.addActionListener(LC);
        but3.addActionListener(LC);
        but4.addActionListener(LC);
        but5.addActionListener(LC);
        but6.addActionListener(LC);
        but7.addActionListener(LC);

        b1.addActionListener(LC);
        b2.addActionListener(LC);
        b3.addActionListener(LC);
        b4.addActionListener(LC);
        b5.addActionListener(LC);
        b6.addActionListener(LC);
        b7.addActionListener(LC);
        b8.addActionListener(LC);
        b9.addActionListener(LC);
        b0.addActionListener(LC);

        jfrm.add(jlab);
        jfrm.add(b1);
        jfrm.add(b2);
        jfrm.add(b3);
        jfrm.add(but1);
        jfrm.add(b4);
        jfrm.add(b5);
        jfrm.add(b6);
        jfrm.add(but2);
        jfrm.add(b7);
        jfrm.add(b8);
        jfrm.add(b9);
        jfrm.add(but3);
        jfrm.add(but5);
        jfrm.add(b0);
        jfrm.add(but6);
        jfrm.add(but7);

    }
    public void set_jlab(String newText) {
        jlab.setText(newText);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new calc_97_lvl();
            }
        });
    }
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ListenCalc implements ActionListener {

    double numberResult;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        resultGiver(ae.getActionCommand());
    }

    public double resultGiver(String textResult) {
        StringTokenizer ST = new StringTokenizer(textResult, "+-*/e", true);

        String s1 = ST.nextToken();
        String s2 = ST.nextToken();
        String s3 = ST.nextToken();
        double op1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        double op2 = Double.parseDouble(s3);
        if (s2.equals("+")) {
            numberResult = op1 + op2;
        } else if (s2.equals("-")) {
            numberResult = op1 - op2;
        } else if (s2.equals("*")) {
            numberResult = op1 * op2;
        } else if (s2.equals("/")) {
            numberResult = op1 / op2;
        } else {}
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: а суть проблемы то в чем? если те ошибки что ниже кода. то тут все просто. все что ниже строки 96 надо поместить в отдельный файл

Comment: лень, реально лень

Comment: К чему тут лень?
В эклипсе все правильно и не работает
Как после обработки кнопки опяты передавать управление пользователю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Че-то вы тут накуролесили аж страшно смотреть на код.

1. На фига все напихали в конструктор вашего класса?
2. На фига еще и вызов конструктора запихали в асинхронный вызов обработчика сообщений оконной системы.

Надо все делать проще и деревяннее - слишком много думали и мало читали документацию.

Возьмите за основу [такой пример](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/ch05/SimpleButtonGroupExample.java), а если не хватит [почерпните мудрость тут](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/)

Comment: Спасибо     ..